# How to open a .bat file (eg which opens RandomApp.exe) correctly from Delphi7?

Tags: windows, delphi, batch-file, cmd, delphi-7

I've searched a lot and I don't quite find the correct answer.

Directory:

- Project (This folder contains the delphi code and a folder called "RunThis"

  - RunThis

    - RandomApp.exe
    - Run.bat
    - Config.txt

Run.bat code

```
start %cd%\RandomApp.exe
pause
```

Delphi 7 (Executes this code on the click of a button.)

```
ShellExecute (application.handle, 'open', 'cmd', PChar('cmd.exe /c RunThis\Run.bat'), nil, SW_MAXIMIZE
```

If I don't add the 'cmd.exe /c' part for the directory, Delphi will open a cmd without any of my code. Similiar to if one had to run cmd.exe .However, if I add the 'cmd.exe /c', then it opens the Run.bat correctly.

Windows the gives me this error:
Windows cannot find 'C:\Project\RunThis\RandomApp.exe' .Make sure you typed the name the name correctly, and then try again.

What's funny about this is that if I just double click on Run.bat, it excutes perfectly. However, when I open it through Delphi it gives me this error. I thought maybe the Run.bat current address had a problem. So Instead of saying:

```
start RandomApp.exe
```

I used the full current directory instead:

```
start %cd%\RandomApp.exe
```

Just to add, when I got Delphi 7 to just open the program directly such as:

```
ShellExecute(Handle, 'open', PChar('RunThis\RandomApp.exe'),null, null, SW_SHOWNORMAL) ;
```

The program gave me an error that it couldn't find "Config.txt". RandomApp.exe uses a text file that stores all its settings.

Again, if I simply click on Run.bat or RandomApp.exe, they both execute perfectly. The problem is when I try to open it with code. I have the feeling that it has to do with the directory but I don't know well.

Thank you very much.

PS: Running Windows 10.

Comment: Why would you ask the shell to create a cmd process to execute a script to create a process. Why not create a process. Turn 4 steps into 1.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Hey, thanks for taking the time to reply. Please do take note that your answer could be much more helpful if it included some guidance or links to the desired advice. So if you could, please assist me with such? Thank you.

Comment: Call CreateProcess and pass in the path to the executable file.

Answer (score 5):

Don't rely on relative paths, always use absolute paths.

`RandomApp.exe` is likely using a relative path to find `Config.txt`, but when you run it from your app, the current working directory is your project folder, not the `RunThis` folder. That is why `RandomApp.exe` can't find the file. So pass the correct folder to `ShellExecute()`, eg:

```
var
  Folder: string; 
begin
  Folder := ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)+'RunThis\' ;
  ShellExecute(Application.Handle, nil, PChar(Folder+'Run.bat'), nil, PChar(Folder), SW_MAXIMIZE);
end;
```

Comment: This works perfectly in Delphi 7. The 1st parameter (the HWND) can be `0`, and you'll want to experiment with the last parameter. Other options include `SW_SHOWNORMAL` and `SW_SHOWMINIMIZED`.

Comment: @AlainD the HWND *can* be 0, but *shouldnt* be 0, if you have one available. In fact, since the code is in a Button click, I would use the Form's HWND instead of the Application's.

Comment: In reality there should be no call to ShellExecute, no owner window, just a call to CreateProcess.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I want to offer you a million of thanks! I really appreciate the time you took to answer my question. This is absolutely correct and worked perfectly. Thanks for teaching me too.